# Deploying Perl Docker Container to Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: git, perl, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am building a Docker container that pulls a perl/mojolicious repo from bitbucket but I am having problems. I have my Dockerfile like this:

```
# DOCKER-VERSION 0.3.4
FROM        perl:latest
MAINTAINER  My Name myname@name.com

# Update aptitude with new repo
RUN apt-get update

# Install software 
RUN apt-get install -y git
# Make ssh dir
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/

# Copy over private key, and set permissions
ADD repo-key /root/.ssh/id_rsa

# Create known_hosts
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
# Add bitbuckets key
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
RUN cpanm Mojolicious

RUN cachebuster=b953b35 git clone -b branch git@bitbucket.org:org/project.git

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR project
CMD hypnotoad script/project
```

And, locally, upon `docker build -t name/project .` it builds fine and says "Successfully built."

I zipped it with the repo-key file and fed that to Elastic Beanstalk, I clicked Upload and Deploy (I successfully deployed the 2048 game sample, and tried to replicate it).

This comes back with `Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory`. Which I think is strange because the documentation says Dockerfile or Dockerrun.aws.json can be used independently for different needs. But whatever, I gave it a short, hopefully inconsequential, Dockerrun.aws.json, like so:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Ports": [
        {"ContainerPort": "8080"}
    ],
    "Volumes": []
}
```

It still fails and the log now states `[CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/04run.sh] command failed with error code 1:` and further `Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch`.

Can someone help me troubleshoot these files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that `hypnotoad` runs in the background by default and this makes the container die instantly. By adding the `-f` flag, it runs in the foreground and the container persists. I also switched `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT`.

```
#... same as above except for last line

WORKDIR project
ENTRYPOINT [ "hypnotoad", "-f", "./script/project" ]
```

You still have to feed EB both Dockerfile and Dockerrun.aws.json for no apparent reason, but even so, it works without error.